# Calling Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges again with its output gives different results

Tags: .net, graphics, text-rendering

When I call Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges twice with the same text and format flags, but using the output rectangle from the first call as the bounding rectangle for the second call, the result gets smaller. If the original result properly bounds the text, shouldn't the result be the same for any subsequent call that passes in the rectangle it gave me the first time?

Here's my code and results (inline):

```
    private static void MeasureStringTest()
    {
        var size = MeasureString("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 500.0f, 100.0f);
    }

    private static Size MeasureString(string text, float width, float height)
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)width, (int)height))
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            StringFormat format = new StringFormat
            {
                FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces | StringFormatFlags.NoClip | StringFormatFlags.NoFontFallback
            };

            RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(0, 0, width, height);
            CharacterRange[] ranges = { new CharacterRange(0, text.Length) };

            format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges);

            // First call, using the given dimensions
            Region[] regions1 = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, rect, format);
            RectangleF result1 = regions1[0].GetBounds(graphics);

            // result1.Width: 159.0; result1.Height: 17.0

            // Second call, using the bounding rectangle from the first call
            Region[] regions2 = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, result1, format);
            RectangleF result2 = regions2[0].GetBounds(graphics);

            // result2.Width: 142.0; result2.Height: 17.0

            // Third call, using an empty bounding rectangle
            Region[] regions3 = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 0), format);
            RectangleF result3 = regions3[0].GetBounds(graphics);

            // result3.Width: 159.0; result3.Height: 17.0

            return new Size((int)result1.Width, (int)result1.Height);
        }
    }
```

Conceptually, here's how I feel the conversation is going:

> - Me: If I had 500 pixels, how many of them would I need to fit
>     this string?
> - Graphics: You'd need 159 pixels.
> - Me: If I had 159 pixels, how many of them would I need to fit this string?
> - Graphics: You'd need 142 pixels.
> - Me: I thought you said I needed 159 pixels?

When I draw the text and a bounding rectangle to a Bitmap and display it on the screen (using a PictureBox control), I see that the original result (159x17) **does** correctly bound the text. Unfortunately, the project I am working on depends on this function for more complicated layout scenarios than I have described here, and I am having trouble debugging it without understanding the issue I have outlined above.